# Field don't get the correct value based of a trigger

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, trigger, custom-field, sum

I have a salesforce object which has the api name: Investissement_Materiel__c.
This object contains the following fields: Id, Date__c, Investment__c, Amount__c, Total__c and Concept__c .

The Concept__c field is of type lookup with the Concept_c object and my lwc component is placed in the layout page of this Concept object

I created a trigger to automatically create 10 investment object records when creating a concept record.

The problem I have exists at the level of the Total field, this field must normally contain a value which is the sum of the 10 values which exist in the amount field, and position this value in the first line of the Total field in the table, and not in the 10 lines, only in the first.

Now the total field always remains empty, so I want your help so that this field contains the exact value which is the sum of the values of the Amount field (Amount__c)

Html :

```
<template>
    <table border="1" style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
            <tr style="padding: inherit;height: 35.5px;">
                <th scope="col" style="width: 15%; text-align: center" ><div class="slds-truncate" title="Date">Date</div></th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 30%;text-align: center"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Investissement">Investissement</div></th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 15%;text-align: center"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Montant">Montant</div></th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 15%;text-align: center"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Total">Total</div></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
            <template if:true={records.length}>

                <template for:each={records} for:item="record" >
                    <tr key={record.Id}>
                        <td>
                            <lightning-input type="date"   
                                            value={record.Date__c} data-id={record.Id}
                                            onchange={handleDateChange} ></lightning-input>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning-input type="text" 
                                             value={record.Investissement__c} data-id={record.Id} 
                                             onchange={handleInvestissementChange}></lightning-input>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning-input type="number"
                                             value={record.Montant__c} data-id={record.Id} 
                                             onchange={handleMontantChange}></lightning-input>
                        </td>
                        <td if:true={isFirstRow}>
                            <lightning-input type="number" 
                                        value={totalMontant} 
                                        readonly>
                                    </lightning-input>
                       </td>
                                
                               
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </template>


        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

JS :

```
const DEFAULT_ROW_COUNT = 10;

export default class Investissement extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId; 
    @track records = [];

    @track isFirstRow = false;
    @track totalMontant = 0;


    connectedCallback() {
        this.initializeRecords();
        this.loadRecords();
    }

    initializeRecords() 
    {
        for (let i = 0; i < DEFAULT_ROW_COUNT; i++) {
            this.records.push({
                Id: i,
               Investissement__c: '',
               Montant__c:'',
               Date__c:'',
               Total__c:'',
              
            });
        }
    }
    
   
    handleInvestissementChange(event) {
        const conceptId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        const inputValue = event.target.value;

        saveInvestissement({ conceptId: conceptId, responseValueInvestissement: inputValue })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Response saved successfully investissement');
                console.log('conceptId is'+conceptId);
                console.log('inputValue is'+inputValue);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error saving response investissement:', JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    }



    handleMontantChange(event) {
        const conceptId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        const inputValue = event.target.value;
        saveMontant({ conceptId: conceptId, responseValue: inputValue })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Response saved successfully montant');
                console.log('conceptId is'+conceptId);
                console.log('inputValue is'+inputValue);

                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.computeAndSaveTotal();
                }, 1000);

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error saving response montant:', JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    }
    handleDateChange(event) {
        const conceptId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        const inputValue = event.target.value;
        console.log('conceptId is'+conceptId);

        saveDate({ conceptId: conceptId, responseValue: inputValue })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Response saved successfully date');
                console.log('conceptId is'+conceptId);
                console.log('inputValue is'+inputValue);

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error saving response date:', JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    }


    computeAndSaveTotal() {
        // Calculate the total for the current record

        console.log('In computeAndSaveTotal');

        let total = 0;
        this.records.forEach(record => {
            total += record.Montant__c ? parseFloat(record.Montant__c) : 0;
        });

        // Update total for the first record
        if (this.records.length > 0) {
            this.records[0].Total__c = total;
            console.log('total is'+total);
        }
    }


    loadRecords() {
        retrieveRecords({ conceptId: this.recordId })
            .then((result) => {
                this.records = result || [];

                console.log('retrieveRecords : record ID is ' + this.recordId);

          
                // Calculate and save the initial total
                this.computeAndSaveTotal();

                if (this.records.length > 0) {
                    console.log('In If ');
                    this.isFirstRow = true;
                    this.totalMontant = this.records[0].Total__c;
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error loading records:', JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    }
}
```

Apex

```
public with sharing class ConceptInvestissement {
    
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void saveDate(Id conceptId, Date responseValue) {
        Investissement_Materiel__c recordsToUpdate = [
            SELECT Id, Date__c
            FROM Concept_Investissement_Materiel__c
            WHERE Id = :conceptId
            LIMIT 1
        ];
        recordsToUpdate.Date__c = responseValue;
        update recordsToUpdate;
  
        System.debug('No record found for conceptId: ' + conceptId);
   
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void saveInvestissement(Id conceptId, String responseValueInvestissement) {
       Concept_Investissement_Materiel__c recordsToUpdate = [
           SELECT Id, Investissement__c
           FROM Concept_Investissement_Materiel__c
           WHERE Id = :conceptId LIMIT 1
        ];

    
        recordsToUpdate.Investissement__c = responseValueInvestissement;
   

        update recordsToUpdate;
        System.debug('No records found for conceptId: ' + conceptId);
   
    }

    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void saveMontant(Id conceptId, Decimal responseValue) {
        Investissement_Materiel__c montantToUpdateList = [
            SELECT Id,_Montant__c
            FROM Investissement_Materiel__c
            WHERE Id = :conceptId
            LIMIT 1
        ];
    
   
        montantToUpdateList.Montant__c = responseValue;
        update montantToUpdateList;
   
        System.debug('No record found for montantId: ' + conceptId);
  
    }
   

  
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Investissement_Materiel__c> retrieveRecords(Id conceptId) {
        List<Investissement_Materiel__c> records = new List<Investissement_Materiel__c>();

        records = [SELECT Id, Date__c,Investissement__c, Montant__c, Total__c
                   FROM Investissement_Materiel__c
                   WHERE Concept__c = :conceptId
                   ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC ];

        return records;
    }

}
```

Trigger

```
trigger CreateConceptInvestissement on Concept__c (after insert) {
    List<Investissement_Materiel__c> ConceptList = new List<Investissement_Materiel__c>();

    for (Concept__c conceptRecord : Trigger.new) {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Investissement_Materiel__c  Concept = new Investissement_Materiel__c();
            
         
            Concept.Date__c = null;
            Concept.Investissement__c = '';
            
            Concept.Montant__c = null;
            Concept.Total__c = null;
            Concept.Concept__c = conceptRecord.Id;

            ConceptList.add(Concept);
        }
    }

    insert ConceptList;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to make the `Investissement_Materiel__c` a master detail child of `Concept__c` then use a rollup summary field to collect the `Total__c`?

Comment: Yes, if you want a total of the child records, then you need a Total field in the parent Concept object.  You should not be summing the 10 investissement records into the first investissement record.

Comment: thank you @PhilW